# In Python 2, creating a random question from shuffled numbers

Tags: python, shuffle

I hope I can get some help with this, I've had absolutely no luck looking online. well that and the fact I'm new to Python.

I'm going through Learn Python The Hard Way, and am really starting to like python. So I made a simple little game. I'm looking for a way to "cheat death", and my idea is that to escape death, you need to answer a math question, and if you get it right, you'd go back to start(), or if you dot it wrong, you'd go to dead(). So here's the code that I have for this question so far:

```
from random import shuffle

numbers = [1, 75, 64, 80275, 2, 7]

shuffle(numbers)

def question(numbers):
```

Now from here, using my list of numbers, I con't quite know how to import the shuffled numbers. I am thinking to have a preset question like this:

```
__ + __ / __ * __ - __ * __
```

So that it'll bring in the list of numbers that've been shuffled, and then substitute __ for the corresponding __ in the question. Then, I'll have:

```
print "Your answer:"
user_answer = raw_input("> ")
```

So they can put in their answer. After this, I will need a way to verify the answer, so I'll do this:

```
if useranswer == answer:
    print "You lived!"
    start()
else:
    dead()
```

Where the variable 'answer' is what python will return as the answer. So, at the end, here's something I think the code should look like:

```
from random import shuffle

numbers = [1, 75, 64, 80275, 2, 7]

question = shuffle(numbers)

def cheat_death(numbers):
    answer = __ + __ / __ * __ - __ * __
    print "You have one chance to cheat death.\nTo do this, you must answer the following question:"
    print question
    user_answer = raw_input("> ")

    if user_answer == answer:
        start()
    else:
        dead()
```

Ok, I have a working piece of code. It generates random numbers, and then puts them into a question. here's the code:

```
i = 0
numbers = []

while i < 6:
    numbers.append(random.randrange(1,900))

    i = i + 1


def cheat_death(numbers):
    shuffle(numbers)
    question = "%d + %d / %d * %d - %d * %d" % tuple(numbers)
    print "You have a single chance to cheat death. To live, please answer the question correctly below:"
    print question
    answer = eval(question)
    user_answer = raw_input("> ")
    if user_answer == answer:
        start()
    else:
        dead()

cheat_death()
```

But every single time I enter an answer, whether it's right or not, it says it's wrong. Could this be because of the eval(question)? Or man I just don't know!

Comment: So what is your question?... we like it when you get stuck and ask how to get around your specific problem :)

Comment: Don't forget to be careful with division in Python 2-- "1/75" is 0, and "75/64" is 1..  Even in Python 3, you'd have to worry about rounding, so you're probably going to want to make sure that numbers[1] is a multiple of numbers[2], which is easily done.

Comment: Sorry for being kind of vague! Well I guess my question would be how to shuffle a list of numbers, or even randomly generate a list of numbers and shuffle them, then perform a math question using these numbers

Comment: Ok, I've got a working piece of code, but when I give the right answer to the math question, it'll always say it's wrong. I'll edit the question and put in the code

Comment: I think I've got it! I tried changing the user_answer to a floating number, by using: floating_answer = float(user_answer)

Comment: yes, that's the answer (was just going to post it...).  you're reading the input as a string, but the eval will be returning a number.  you could also use `float(user_answer) == float(answer)` or `user_answer == str(answer)`.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose I could, and that way I know 100%, even though it would return a number, that way I know everything will be read as a number. Would I be able to email someone for more help? I've ran into MORE problems now because of this addition to the script

Answer (score 2):

```
from random import shuffle

numbers = [1, 75, 64, 80275, 2, 7]
shuffle(numbers)
print numbers
# [80275, 64, 75, 2, 7, 1]
question = "%d + %d / %d * %d - %d * %d" % tuple(numbers)
print question 
# 80275 + 64 / 75 * 2 - 7 * 1
answer = eval(question)
print answer
# 80269.7066667
```

Comment: And then, you [`eval(question)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval)?

Comment: This looks like just what I need! Thanks for the input! So I guess all I needed was tuple() and eval()

Answer (score 0):

```
def cheat_death(numbers):
    answer = eval('{0}+{1}/{2}*{3}-{4}*{5}'.format(*numbers))
    print "You have one chance to cheat death.\nTo do this, you must answer the following question:"
    print '{0}+{1}/{2}*{3}-{4}*{5}'.format(*numbers)
    user_answer = raw_input("> ")

    if user_answer == answer:
        start()
    else:
        dead()
```

I think this is what you would need.  Upon each call, you would likely want to shuffle the numbers again, or could even add a function that randomly generates the numbers (and likely the questions) within certain ranges.

Comment: I really like your code here, but I have another question, is there a way to either tell how Python rounds numbers, or is there a way to specify how to round the number?

Comment: I might incorporate:

        i = 0
    numbers = []
    
    while i < 6:
        print "At top is %d" % i
        numbers.append(random.randrange(1,7))
    
        i = i + 1
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        print "At the bottom i is %d" % i
    
        
    print "The numbers:"
    
    for num in numbers:
        print num

Something like that to get the random numbers